# Not seeing the "Connected to iAd" popups on my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iad, interstitial

I am in the process of making an iOS app (Objective-C), I am nearing the end of my production of the application itself and now I am trying to implements `Interstitial Ads`. I was before seeing the Blue **You are connected to iAd** banners before on my app but I do not seem to see them now. My test device (iPhone 5S, iOS 9.2.1) is connected to the internet, so that is not the issue and the account I am using is a free developer account, not a paid one.

Below is code from one of my view controllers (the code is identical on all three of them with regard to iAd), I got the code from Apple's test project and modified it slightly.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[self cycleInterstitial];

// Other non-relavent stuff

}




- (void)like: (UIButton*)button {

// Other non-relavent stuff    

NSInteger i = arc4random_uniform(3);

if (i == 2) {
    [self presentInterlude];
}
}

- (void)cycleInterstitial {
// Clean up the old interstitial...
NSLog(@"Cycling");
self.inter.delegate = nil;
// and create a new interstitial. We set the delegate so that we can be notified of when
self.inter = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];

self.inter.delegate = self;
}

- (void)presentInterlude {
// If the interstitial managed to load, then we'll present it now.
if (self.inter.loaded) {
    NSLog(@"Requesting the ad");
    [self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
}

}



- (void)interstitialAdDidUnload:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
[self cycleInterstitial];
}


- (void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
[self cycleInterstitial];
}
```

I know it is not my random number as I removed that previously. ***Any ideas on why my ads are not showing up?*** Could it be my code, my non-paid developer account, or is it something else?

I am not trying to display an actual ad I am only trying to get that ***You are connected to iAd*** popup to display to confirm that my implementation is working, so it should not be the fact that I am using a non-paid developer account.

Comment: I think you can only view them on a simulator, because you will not have any ads before Apple will approve your app and assign the ads for you app.
However even after they will approve and assign the iAds are not available in every country. (In my country they are not :( ) So I never saw my ads.

Comment: Add a `print` statement to your `-(void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` to print the `error` so you know why its failing.